Why are my Angular services not being mocked in unit tests?
I have a pretty simple app component that just calls a method on an injected service:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly userService = inject(UserService);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.init();
  }
}

I am trying to write unit tests to cover this:
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let app: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let injectedUserSvc: UserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppComponent, ToastrModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [provideHttpClient(), provideHttpClientTesting(), provideRouter([])],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.componentInstance;
    injectedUserSvc = TestBed.inject(UserService);
  });

  it('should create the app and initialize the user service', () => {
    spyOn(injectedUserSvc, 'init');
    fixture.detectChanges(); //triggers ngOnInit()

    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    expect(injectedUserSvc.init).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith();
  });
});

When I do this, it complains about a service downstream from the UserService not properly being provided with some data. So this means it's actually executing the code in my UserService as well as everything insjected into it. Why?
I have written Angular tests in the past on other projects, and I have compared my code. I don't think I'm actually doing anything different. Does Angular not automatically provide mocks for things inject into a test?  Am I supposed to do something like spyOn(injectedUserSvc, 'init').and.callFake(() => {}) instead to to test if it's being called or not?

No it does not automatically mock, please share the error and the service, so that the question has all the details

The specific details shouldn't matter about the downstream service here. I just want to have my service mocked here so that my test on this component is ONLY running code related to this component. I don't want to test my service here, just the fact that it should be called

Because you're not mocking them. "Does Angular not automatically provide mocks" - no. Use the DI system to do that, provide a test double so you don't need to spy on the real thing. Angular has extensive guidance on testing: https://angular.dev/guide/testing

is it jasmine or jest? If it's jasmine, you should use spyOn().and.callthrough().
